# Do Mach-O shared libraries (`.dylib`s) support symbol versioning?

Tags: shared-libraries, dylib, dynamic-library, mach-o

I'm running into some segfaults that seem to be resolved on linux platforms by [symbol versioning](https://maskray.me/blog/2020-11-26-all-about-symbol-versioning) inside the ELF dynamic libraries.  But I'm still getting segfaults on macOS.  Is there a comparable feature in Mach-O shared libraries?  And if so, how can I see the version information in the file?

For example, I know that on linux I can do `readelf -s libsomething.so`, and it will output the version info along with the symbols.  But `readelf` chokes on `.dylib` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but you can kinda roll your own.

To serve as an example, Apple has actually done some kind of symbol versioning to the `stat()` family of functions. Depending on macro definitions, the declaration of `stat` will expand to either this:

```c
int stat(const char *, struct stat *) __asm("_stat");
```

Or this:

```c
int stat(const char *, struct stat *) __asm("_stat$INODE64");
```

And this is what the library exports look like:

```
% nm -arch x86_64 /usr/lib//system/libsystem_kernel.dylib | fgrep ' _stat'
0000000000009650 T _stat
0000000000001fd8 T _stat$INODE64
0000000000001fd8 T _stat64
00000000000250dc T _statfs
0000000000002e4c T _statfs$INODE64
0000000000002e4c T _statfs64
```

(Note that you *have* to use the x86_64 version there, as the arm64 version never had the old implementation to begin with, and so `_stat` there is already the new version.)

But if you're just a user of a library, then unless you have broken headers with mismatched struct and function definitions, then this is not going to solve your segfault issue.